# Remove elements by index in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm new in haskell and I'm looking for some standard functions to work with lists by indexes.

My exact problem is that i want to remove 3 elements after every 5. If its not clear enough here is illustration:

```
OOOOOXXXOOOOOXXX...
```

I know how to write huge function with many parameters, but is there any clever way to do this?

Comment: yes, `g n m = map take m . takeWhile (not.null) . unfoldr (Just . splitAt (n+m))` and call it as `g 3 5 "yourstring"`. import `Data.List` for the `unfoldr`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Two completely different approaches

1. You can use [`List.splitAt`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3AsplitAt) together with [`drop`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Adrop):

   ```
   import Data.List (splitAt)
   f :: [a] -> [a]
   f [] = []
   f xs = let (h, t) = splitAt 5 xs in h ++ f (drop 3 t)
   ```

   Now `f [1..12]` yields `[1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12]`. Note that this function can be expressed more elegantly using [`uncurry`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Auncurry) and [`Control.Arrow.second`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html#v%3Asecond):

   ```
   import Data.List (splitAt)
   import Control.Arrow (second)
   f :: [a] -> [a]
   f [] = []
   f xs = uncurry (++) $ second (f . drop 3) $ splitAt 5 xs
   ```

   Since we're using [`Control.Arrow`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html) anyway, we can opt to drop `splitAt` and instead call in the help of [`Control.Arrow.(&&&)`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html#v%3A%26%26%26), combined with [`take`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Atake):

   ```
   import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
   f :: [a] -> [a]
   f [] = []
   f xs = uncurry (++) $ (take 5 &&& (f . drop 8)) xs
   ```

   But now it's clear that an even shorter solution is the following:

   ```
   f :: [a] -> [a] 
   f [] = []
   f xs = take 5 xs ++ (f . drop 8) xs
   ```

   As [Chris Lutz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60777/chris-lutz) notes, this solution can then be generalized as follows:

   ```
   nofm :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
   nofm _ _ [] = []
   nofm n m xs = take n xs ++ (nofm n m . drop m) xs
   ```

   Now `nofm 5 8` yields the required function. *Note that a solution with `splitAt` may still be more efficient!*
2. Apply some mathematics using [`map`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Amap), [`snd`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Asnd), [`filter`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Afilter), [`mod`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Amod) and [`zip`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Azip):

   ```
   f :: [a] -> [a]
   f = map snd . filter (\(i, _) -> i `mod` 8 < (5 :: Int)) . zip [0..]
   ```

   The idea here is that we pair each element in the list with its index, a natural number *i*. We then remove those elements for which *i % 8 > 4*. The general version of this solution is:

   ```
   nofm :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
   nofm n m = map snd . filter (\(i, _) -> i `mod` m < n) . zip [0..]
   ```

Comment: +1 solution two is easily generalizable to `NofM :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]` taking two arguments to put in place of 8 and 5, respectively. It also has the advantage of being quite clearly named.

Answer (score 18):

Here is my take:

```
deleteAt idx xs = lft ++ rgt
  where (lft, (_:rgt)) = splitAt idx xs
```

Answer (score 6):

You can count your elements easily:

```
strip' (x:xs) n | n == 7 = strip' xs 0
                | n >= 5 = strip' xs (n+1)
                | n < 5 = x : strip' xs (n+1)
strip l = strip' l 0
```

Though open-coding looks shorter:

```
strip (a:b:c:d:e:_:_:_:xs) = a:b:c:d:e:strip xs
strip (a:b:c:d:e:xs) = a:b:c:d:e:[]
strip xs = xs
```

Comment: I like the second version, but it's not generalizabe. Which is unfortunate, because it's possibly the clearest solution here.

Comment: I like the pattern-matching solution. Simple as it can possibly be. Though you might need some more to match lists of less than eight elements. Can never remember how that works.

Answer (score 5):

Since nobody did a version with "unfoldr", here is my take:

```
drop3after5 lst = concat $ unfoldr chunk lst
  where
    chunk [] = Nothing
    chunk lst = Just (take 5 lst, drop (5+3) lst)
```

Seems to be the shortest thus far

Comment: Concat function is needed to final result.

Answer (score 2):

the `take` and `drop` functions may be able to help you here.

```
drop, take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

from these we could construct a function to do one step.

```
takeNdropM :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
takeNdropM n m list = (take n list, drop (n+m) list)
```

and then we can use this to reduce our problem

```
takeEveryNafterEveryM :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
takeEveryNafterEveryM n m [] = []
takeEveryNafterEveryM n m list = taken ++ takeEveryNafterEveryM n m rest
    where
        (taken, rest) = takeNdropM n m list

*Main> takeEveryNafterEveryM 5 3 [1..20]
[1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,17,18,19,20]
```

---

since this is not a primitive form of recursion, it is harder to express this as a simple fold.

so a new folding function could be defined to fit your needs

```
splitReduce :: ([a] -> ([a], [a])) -> [a] -> [a]
splitReduce f []   = []
splitReduce f list = left ++ splitReduce f right
    where
        (left, right) = f list
```

then the definition of `takeEveryNafterEveryM` is simply

```
takeEveryNafterEveryM2 n m = splitReduce (takeNdropM 5 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution. It's a lot like [@barkmadley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736028/remove-elements-by-index-in-haskell/1736107#1736107), using only `take` and `drop`, but with less clutter in my opinion:

```
takedrop :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
takedrop _ _ [] = []
takedrop n m l  = take n l ++ takedrop n m (drop (n + m) l)
```

Not sure if it'll win any awards for speed or cleverness, but I think it's pretty clear and concise, and it certainly works:

```
*Main> takedrop 5 3 [1..20]
[1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,17,18,19,20]
*Main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
remElements step num=rem' step num
    where rem' _ _ []=[]
          rem' s n (x:xs)
              |s>0 = x:rem' (s-1) num xs
              |n==0 = x:rem' (step-1) num xs
              |otherwise= rem' 0 (n-1) xs
```

example:

```
*Main> remElements 5 3 [1..20]
[1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,17,18,19,20]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myRemove = map snd . filter fst . zip (cycle $ (replicate 5 True) ++ (replicate 3 False))
```