# Delete list elements by looking on another list

Tags: haskell

I have two lists. One list contains some random data and other list contains the index of first list which needs to be deleted.

For example, let us consider two lists:

```
let a = [3,4,5,6,6,7,8]
let b = [1,3]
```

Then, the resultant output should be `[3,5,6,7,8]`. The number 4 and 6 are deleted since they are on index positions 1 and 3 respectively.

I'm new to Haskell, so finding it difficult to find the solution.

Update: Following code makes it work

```
import Data.List
dele :: Eq a => [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
dele [] _ = []
dele x [] = x
dele x (y:ys) = dele (delete (x !! y) x) ys
```

I was just wondering, is there a way to solve it through map/fold way ?

Comment: it's a functional programming language, which means that side effects  and mutable data structures are out the door! Any solution will involve recreating a partial list with the items you want.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097501/learning-haskell-how-to-remove-an-item-from-a-list-in-haskell and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736028/remove-elements-by-index-in-haskell

Comment: Question Updated. Made it work now, through pattern matching. I'm wondering if there is a better way of solving this ?

Comment: Your solution is not really working. Try `dele [1,2,3,4,5,1] [5]`.

Comment: @n.m.Thanks for pointing it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
deleteByIndex :: (Enum a, Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> [b] -> [b]
deleteByIndex r = map snd . filter (\(i, _) -> notElem i r) . zip [0..]
```

`[0..]` produces an infinite list `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]`

`zip` constructs a list of pairs with the values of this list and your input list in the form `[(0,x), (1, y), ...]`

`filter` takes a function `a -> Bool`. The lambda checks if the index (first element of the pair) is in your input list `r`.

`map snd` returns the second element of each pair of the zip list.

`zip`,`filter`, `map` and `notElem` are documented [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html)

Comment: It gives wrong output: `*Main Data.List> deleteByIndex [1,2,3,4,5,6] [0,3,2]`. That gives me a resultant list of `[0]` but the correct output list should be `[2,4,5,6]`

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head:

```
removeByIndex :: [Integer] -> [a] -> [a]
removeByIndex indices = map snd . filter notInIndices . zip [0..]
    where notInIndices (i,_) = i `notElem` indices
```

Comment: Zounds, beaten to the punch! :D

Comment: Nice answer! This is how I thought of it: `[ x | x <- a , notElem (fromJust $ x ``elemIndex`` a) b]` (The only issue is that now b has to be let b= [1, 3] :: [Int])

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer using the lens library which has received considerable attention recently

```
import Control.Lens
>let a = [3,4,5,6,6,7,8]
>let b = [1,3]
>a^..elements (`notElem`b)
[3,5,6,7,8]
```

(^..) is jus the infix for of toListOf which can be used to traverse a structure and make a list out of its parts.  The elements function just lets you choose which ones to include.

Other options are 'traverse' to traverse a traversables, 'both' to traverse a (,) and they compose together with (.) so traverse.both would traverse [(1,2), (3,4)] for example.

> [(1,2), (3,4)]^..traverse.both
>   [1,2,3,4]